# Why isn't my instantaneous validation displaying anything?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have a form that has a number of fields on it. When the user inputs anything, the field should automatically begin sending feedback as to whether or not the input is valid. The javascript code listed is suppose to handle the instantaneous feedback but it gives no reply whatsoever. It is also suppose to stop the form from being submitted if any of the user's input does not match the regular expressions. The regular expressions don't work either but they were working perfectly fine before I used the innerHTML. I would go back to using alerts if using innerHTML wasn't mandatory.

```
function insert() {

   var valid = true;

    document.getElementById("MessNM").innerHTML = "";
    if (!document.getElementById("name").value.match(/^^[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{3,7}$/)) {
        document.getElementById("MessNM").innerHTML = " Please input a proper name.";
        valid = false;
    }

    document.getElementById("MessPS").innerHTML = "";
    if (!document.getElementById("password").value.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,8}$/)) {
        document.getElementById("MessPS").innerHTML = " Please input a proper password with numbers and letters.";
        valid = false;
    }

    document.getElementById("MessPSC").innerHTML = "";
    if (document.getElementById("passwordcheck").value != document.getElementById("password").value) {
        document.getElementById("MessPSC").innerHTML = " Password does not match.";
        valid = false;
    }

    document.getElementById("MessAD").innerHTML = "";
    if (!document.getElementById("address").value.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s,'-]{5,40}$/)) {
        document.getElementById("MessAD").innerHTML = " Address is not valid";
        valid = false;
    }

    document.getElementById("MessZC").innerHTML = "";
    if (!document.getElementById("zipcode").value.match(/^[0-9]{5}$/)) {
        document.getElementById("MessZC").innerHTML = " Please input a proper Zipcode.";
        valid = false;
    }
    if (!document.getElementById("zipcode").value.match(/^[0-9]{5}(-[0-9]{4})?$/)) {
        document.getElementById("MessZC").innerHTML = " Please input a proper Zipcode.";
        valid = false;
    } else {
        return valid;
    }
}

function test() {

    var result = true;

    if (!insert()) {
        result = false;
    }

    return result;
}
```

This is the html form that the javascript function is referencing.

```
<form name="Insert" id="I2" action="order.php" method="post" style="display: none;" onsubmit="return test()">
    <p align="left">
        <div id="texter">
            <input type=text id="name" required="required" onkeyup="insert()" name="name" autocomplete="off" autofocus>Name <span id="MessNM"></span>
            <br>
            <input type=email id="email" required="required" onkeyup="insert()" name="email">Email Address <span id="MessEM"></span>
            <br>
            <input type=password id="password" required="required" onkeyup="insert()" name="password">Password <span id="MessPS"></span>
            <br>
            <input type=password id="passwordcheck" required="required" onkeyup="insert()" name="passwordcheck">Confirm Password <span id="MessPSC"></span>
            <br>
            <input type=text id="address" required="required" onkeyup="insert()" name="address">Address <span id="MessAD"></span>
            <br>
            <input type=text id="zipcode" required="required" onkeyup="insert()" name="zipcode">Zipcode <span id="MessZC"></span>
            <br>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="test()">
        <input type="reset" value="Clear All">
        <br>
        <br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues I see.

1. You have `style="display: none;"` on the form which makes the whole form invisible.
2. Your validation function returns false on the first failed validation which means you're only going to show an error message for the first invalid field, e.g. if e-mail address and zip code are invalid you'll only get a message for e-mail address.
3. The regular expression for the address validation is broken.
4. When the password confirmation error is fixed the error message doesn't clear.

By the fact that you say it was working when you used alerts, I'm guessing the main issue you're talking about is caused by the fact that each field validation returns false. You probably just had alerts before and returned a boolean at the end of the function. Here's a solution that addresses that issue and the others I mentioned above.

```
<form name="Insert" id="I2" action="order.php" method="post" onsubmit="return test()">
    <p align="left">
        <div id="texter">
            <input type=text id="name" required="required" onkeyup="insert()" name="name" autocomplete="off"/>Name <span id="MessNM"></span>
            <br>
            <input type="email" id="email" required="required" onkeyup="insert()" name="email">Email Address <span id="MessEM"></span>
            <br>
            <input type="password" id="password" required="required" onkeyup="insert()" name="password">Password <span id="MessPS"></span>
            <br>
            <input type="password" id="passwordcheck" required="required" onkeyup="insert()" name="passwordcheck">Confirm Password <span id="MessPSC"></span>
            <br>
            <input type="text" id="address" required="required" onkeyup="insert()" name="address">Address <span id="MessAD"></span>
            <br>
            <input type="text" id="zipcode" required="required" onkeyup="insert()" name="zipcode">Zipcode <span id="MessZC"></span>
            <br>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="test()">
        <input type="reset" value="Clear All">
        <br>
        <br>
</form>

function insert() {
    var valid = true;

    document.getElementById("MessNM").innerHTML = "";
    if (!document.getElementById("name").value.match(/^^[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{3,7}$/)) {
        document.getElementById("MessNM").innerHTML = " Please input a proper name.";
        valid = false;
    }

    document.getElementById("MessPS").innerHTML = "";
    if (!document.getElementById("password").value.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,8}$/)) {
        document.getElementById("MessPS").innerHTML = " Please input a proper password with numbers and letters.";
        valid = false;
    }

    document.getElementById("MessPSC").innerHTML = "";
    if (document.getElementById("passwordcheck").value != document.getElementById("password").value) {
        document.getElementById("MessPSC").innerHTML = " Password does not match.";
        valid = false;
    }

    document.getElementById("MessAD").innerHTML = "";                                                           
    if (!document.getElementById("address").value.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s,'-]*$/)) {
        document.getElementById("MessAD").innerHTML = " Address is not valid";
        valid = false;
    }

    document.getElementById("MessZC").innerHTML = "";
    if (!document.getElementById("zipcode").value.match(/^[0-9]{5}$/)) {
        document.getElementById("MessZC").innerHTML = " Please input a proper Zipcode.";
        valid = false;
    }
    if (!document.getElementById("zipcode").value.match(/^[0-9]{5}(-[0-9]{4})?$/)) {
        document.getElementById("MessZC").innerHTML = " Please input a proper Zipcode.";
        valid = false;
    } 

    return valid;
}
```